# How to interpret marginal effects on a dependent variable that is a ratio?

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have run a basic OLS regression in Stata using a basketball data set I created. My dependent variable is a points ratio that divides the home teams final score by the away teams, which means if the home teams ratio is above 1 then they won the game and vice versa. I am using statistics such as field goal percentage and the total number of turnovers in a game as independent variables to see how these numbers correlate with the points ratio. Since the dependent variable typically ranges between 0.8 to 1.2 what I am wondering is:

If I have a coefficient of 0.00382 for the independent variable of field goal percentage would it be interpreted as:
A one percentage point increase in field goal percentage will lead to a 0.00382 increase in the points ratio.

Or would it be interpreted with the decimal place moved:
A one percentage point increase in field goal percentage will lead to a 0.382 increase in the points ratio.

I assume the coefficient would not be interpreted as a percentage since I have not used any log variables. Please feel free to provide any information that would help, thank you all!

Comment: Re your assumption at the end: Any ratio $\rho$ that varies between $0.8$ and $1.2$ is, to a good approximation, the exponential of $\rho-1.$  Thus, taking logs would be the same as subtracting $1$ from the intercept in your model.  In effect, you may treat your response variable as being a constant offset from a logarithm.

Comment: So how would I interpret the given coefficient in a statement?

Comment: Apart from the intercept, you could interpret it the same way you would if the response were the (natural) logarithm.

Comment: @whuber So could I interpret as: A one percentage point increase in field goal percentage would lead to a 0.382 % increase in the points ratio. Or would it be another way? I have also had experience with interpreting the other combinations of logs, so please let me know what would work.

Comment: We have a large number of threads about this topic to help you out: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+interpret+log+score%3A2 for some of them.